# Change/replace the element of value of variable based on row number

Tags: r

I'm new to R and was trying to change the value of the element of one variable based on row number but was getting error message.

I have a data that has 3 variables (columns) and one of them is 'Date'. I want to change the value of 'Date' on rows 234:340 to 5/21/2018.

Thank you.

Comment: `df1[234:340, 'date'] <- as.Date("05-21-2018",  format = "%m-%d-%Y")` - read up on "indexing" in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read a little on indexing data frames in R. You can specify columns (and rows) in a few ways. For example, to specify the date column you can use:

```
df1[, 'date']
df1[, 1] # (assuming date is the first column)
df1$date
```

You index the rows similarly, but indexing before the comma:

```
df1[1, ] # selects the first row
df1[1:20, ] # selects the first 20 rows
```

Combine these and assign the new value to solve your problem, with all three of these having the same effect:

```
df1[234:340, 'date'] <- as.Date("05-21-2018", format = "%m-%d-%Y")
df1[234:340, 1]      <- as.Date("05-21-2018", format = "%m-%d-%Y")
df1$date[234:340]    <- as.Date("05-21-2018", format = "%m-%d-%Y")
```